# Provide step by step multi-option instructions in MediaWiki pages

Tags: templates, mediawiki, show-hide

We have a wiki page in MediaWiki with instructions like this:

- complete instruction 1
- also in case A do this
- complete instruction 2
- also in case B do this
- complete instruction 3
- etc

Is there a way to show just the lines / paragraphs in which we are interested? E.g. someone could show **all** rows or hide certain rows, preferably at the touch of a button.

I assume it is some combination of tables, [ToggleDisplay](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aToggleDisplay) and templates but I don't know more than that. Any else know?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but maybe you could use Collapsible tables and build your instructions as a two column table like the second one shown under [Simple Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCollapsible_tables#Simple_example)

Looked a little further how about the [NavFrame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aNavFrame) I know it is deprecated but I think it might be able to handle what you want?

Comment: the problem here is that we will need to open each row separately I guess. Nice thinking though. You got me wondering whether I could show / hide a whole second column. I'll get back to you if I can.

Comment: My idea was actually to have the parts that you wanted to be able to hide in column two like:
1) Do something
               Also do A if something
And then have one button to hide/show the second column, but it might not be a desirable way to solve the problem I can see that.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to put each section in a template like this: Template A; Template B; Template C; Template D.

Then have **two pages** (with links between) where say, page 1 is {{Template A}}{{Template C}} and page 2 is {{Template A}}{{Template B}}{{Template C}}{{Template D}}.

But that's not elegant - any better ideas?